# Exported file save on server. It should be downloaded in system without saving on server

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, fwrite, fclose

I have PHP script to exported record from database in to CSV file. When I click on export button, It creates a CSV file on server (current location). All data are properly being displayed in CSV file but It should not save on server, It should be downloaded in system. This question might be duplicate, but i didn't find answer.

Code for exported data in CSV file.

```
$monthData  = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($monthData);

$output = "";

for ($i = 2; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading = mysql_field_name($monthData,$i);
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($monthData)) {
    for ($i = 2; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";
}
$fileName = $month.'Data.csv';
$csvfile = fopen($fileName, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($csvfile, $output);

fclose($csvfile);
```

As per my research or knowledge, I think there is a need to add some header (that specify fileName, fileSize and many other). I don't have much knowledge about it, why and where do i need to add it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Change `$csvfile = fopen($fileName, "w")` to `$csvfile = fopen('php://output', "w")`.... and send [headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) before doing that.... the examples in the link I've posted show how to send headers for a pdf file, but you should easily be able to change the content type to `text/csv` instead

Comment: @MarkBaker - Thanks for  replying. Now file doesn't download even on server. It shows me warning - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..............There may be my mistake using header in proper way. Can you please post the syntax. It's urgent.

Comment: You have to send your headers before sending anything to `php://output`... if you're getting that particular message even with the headers before opening the file, then something else in your code is sending output to the browser, and the error message should tell you exactly where

Answer (score 1):

Here you go the simple answer to your question.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=testdata.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// fetch the data
$row = array(array('row1val','row1val','row1val'),array('row2val','row2val','row2val')); 

// loop over the rows, outputting them
foreach($row as $fields):
fputcsv($output, $fields);
endforeach;

fclose($output);

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: How can you save the exported file also on server?